# Tab Bar with AVPlayer that gets info from tableview?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uitabbar, avplayer

I have a AVPlayer that playes audio.
What i need is, to have a TableView or something like it, with some names like: Tom Jones, and if that one is selected in the tableview, it passes a string to my AVPlayer, so the AVPlayer changes song.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

many ways to skin this cat.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"audio_url"]]];
}
```

*syntax not verified
this will only work of course if you have defined 'self.player' and 'myArray'
self.player being your AVPlayer and myArray being an array of dictionaries, probably the same one that you would use in your UITableView DataSource

Comment: i have defined my AVPlayer as player, like you did but im gonna try and see if this works.. all tho im getting a bit confused about the "audio_url".. is that the audio url for the selected row or a standard url? because the player needs to play the selected row's url..

Comment: in this example the "audio_url" would be a NSString object like @'http://www.server.com/file.mp3" This is only a lil sample, it problbly wont work right off the bat with your code and or data structure.

Comment: I have tryed the solution, but cant figger out how its working..

in my stationsTableViewController i have added:
stationList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[stationList addObject:@"audio_link"];
 
self.navigationItem.title = @"Stationer";

where audio_link is, i need some kind of text so when i build and go, it need to say ect: "hey" and in that row, the index needs to be the audio link.. and when i press "hey" it passes the audio_link into the AVPlayer in the other view i have..

also, i cant seem to figger out how i combine the AVPlayer and the table view togeather..

Comment: i just tryed again, and it crashes the simulator :/